# Kubernetes Secret in google container engine fails -/ setting oom score for ready process caused error

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-secrets

I created  a service which works perfectly in kubernetes.

Then i moved the connection string to a kubernetes secret; this is my yaml config:

```
    env:
      - name: AZURE_CONNECTION
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: azure
            key: connection-string
```

But since then the the scheduling of the pod fails

> Error: failed to start container "myservice-api-host": Error response
>   from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting
>   container process caused "process_linux.go:295: setting oom score for
>   ready process caused \"write /proc/22658/oom_score_adj: invalid
>   argument\""

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason was that the secret was base64 encoded based on a UTF16 string.

After encoding the secret in **UTF8** then Base64 everything works fine